# Как сделать счетчик побед в txt файле

Tags: c#

У нас есть игра в которой есть два игрока, если один игрок выигрывает то, в txt файл записываем цифру 1, в случаи если выиграет второй игрок, то на следущую строку пишет 1, если выигрывает снова первый игрок, тто счет из 1 меняется на 2

```
using (StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(path, true))
{
     resultCross++;
     sw.Write("Крестики:");
     sw.Write(resultCross + Environment.NewLine);
}
```

Comment: Так и в чем проблема?

Comment: Каким образом это можно сделать ?

Comment: Что сделать? Будьте конкретны. Вы в файл писать не умеете? Или что не получается? Покажите ваш код и ваши попытки решить вашу проблему.

Comment: Проблема в том, когда я пытаюсь второй игрок выигрывает, файл, то он просто пишет его заново

Comment: Так вы сначала считайте прошлый счет из файла, увеличьте нужное число на 1 и перезапишите файл полностью - мне кажется, так будет проще всего.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

К примеру вам нужно записать файл такого формата:

```
Крестики: 0
Нолики: 1
```

Такого объема файл можно просто перезаписать поверх.

Тогда можно написать метод

```cs
private int crossWin;
private int zeroWin;

private void SaveWins(string path)
{
    string text = $"Крестики: {crossWin}{Environment.NewLine}Нолики: {zeroWin}";
    File.WriteAllText(path, text);
}
```

С записью все просто, а прочитать обратно можно вот так

```cs
private void LoadWins(string path)
{
    string[] lines = File.ReadAllLines(path);
    crossWin = int.Parse(lines[0].Split()[1]);
    zeroWin = int.Parse(lines[1].Split()[1]);
}
```

Comment: Каким образом в файле я должен менять счет Крестика у которого 1 на 2 ?

Comment: @Deni `crossWin++; SaveWins("file.txt");`

Comment: С методом LoadWind, когда его надо вызывать ?

Comment: @Deni_ к примеру вы запустили программу и хотите загрузить в переменные то, что сохранили ранее, ну то что в файле хранится - вызываете `LoadWins()`, и готово, в переменных будут те значения, которые были в них ранее перед тем, как вы вызвали `SaveWins()`. Это очень просто работает - загрузка из файла и сохранение в файл.

Comment: Хорошо, спасибо все работает, и еще один вопрос, где можно про запись и чтение файла почитать ? Не считая  метанит

Comment: @Deni_ поставьте курсор на `File` и нажмите F12, вам откроются метаданные - все методы и свойства класса `File`, прямо в студии (это работает с любым методом и классом, проверьте например на `Console`). Слева от каждого метода есть `[...]`, нажмите это, чтобы увидеть описание. Вот [здесь](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/api/system.io.file?view=netframework-4.8) еще можно почитать.

Comment: Хорошо, спасибо

Comment: Что делает метод Split и для чего после него [1] ?

Comment: @Deni_ он возвращает `string[]`, состоящий частей строки, за разделитель по умолчанию принимается пробел. А `[1]`, это обращение ко второму элементу массива строк. `Крестики: 1` разбивается на [0] = `Крестики:` и [1] = `1`, но это [очень легко нагуглить](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/api/system.string.split?view=netframework-4.8).

Comment: Хорошо, спасибо

Comment: Я добавил 2 переменные в LoadWins для счета ничьи и количеств игр, но мне выдают ошибку там где моя последняя строка  "Input string was not in a correct format
"

Comment: @Deni_ Покажите код, отредактируйте вопрос. А лучше вообще задайте новый. Скорее всего вы пытаетесь считать из файла то, чего там еще нет.

Comment: Отредактировал, добавить новый вопрос не могу, так как запретили

Comment: @Deni_ самое простое - допишите от руки в файл то, то надо. Потому что в файле у вас 2 строки, а считать вы пытаетесь 4.

Comment: @Deni_ и не надо было менять вопрос полностью, можно было просто дописать. Я вернул в исходное состояние, потому что мой ответ бы потерял смысл. Там должнол быть "Ничья: 0" и "Количество игр: 0".

Comment: @Deni_ И зачем вам хранить количество игр, если это сумма трех остальных чисел? Это можно просто посчитать `a+b+c`.

Comment: Спасибо за подсказку, дальше я сам

Answer (score -1):

Я кажется понял ваш вопрос,и я думаю что лучше это реализовать через переменные

```
int first_player;
int second_player;
```

И потом при победе добавлять 1 к нужной переменной

```
first_player += 1;
```

Ну и так далее

Comment: Просто  каждый раз когда я перезапускаю игру, то переменные обнуляются

Comment: Ну это и понятно,если это не принципиально можно их сохранять в реестр

Comment: Не надо реестр. Автор хочет использовать файл. Сделайте пример код, как записывать число в файл и потом считывать. Сейчас ваше сообщение не является ответом.